# Neo4j security and user management not available in Enterprise edition

Tags: graph, neo4j, roles, graph-databases, user-management

I am using Neo4j Developer license, it is all working perfectly. However, I am unable to give roles and permissions to the users even though I am using the Enterprise edition.

I am not even able to change passwords because the procedures to do so are not deployed for some reason.

Here's the error I get when I try to view, add or alter user permissions:

```
There is no procedure with the name `dbms.security.listUsers` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.
```

It's said that the Enterprise version has built-in user management and security. But it doesn't seem to be the case here. How can I enable role management on my database?

Comment: If you have downloaded the desktop version, it's normal, it's a single user server, so there is no security management

Comment: You may want to download the standalone enterprise version instead of going through the desktop. Here's the [other downloads page](https://neo4j.com/download/other-releases/).